# Handling Push Notification Navigation to Different Views in Terminated/Kill State in iOS with Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uikit

I am facing an issue with handling push notifications in my iOS app when it is in a terminated/kill state. Here's the scenario:

I have a tab bar controller with four tab bar items: A, B, C, and D. Tab A is the dashboard, which opens after the user logs in. When the app is in the foreground/background state, I can successfully handle push notifications and navigate to different views based on my handleNotification function.

However, when the app is terminated/killed and I generate a push notification, tapping on it only opens the dashboard. What I want is to be able to navigate to different views based on the content of the push notification, even when the app is in the terminated state.

Here are the relevant details:

- I have implemented push notifications using Apple's Push Notification Service (APNS) and Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).
- I have set up the necessary notification categories and actions in my app.
- I've tried to handle the push notification in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate, but it only opens the dashboard.
- I've searched for solutions and tried different approaches, but I haven't been able to find a way to achieve the desired behavior.

  class NotificationHandler {

  static let shared = NotificationHandler()

  func handleNotification(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

  ```
    guard let pushTypeStr = userInfo["type"] as? String,

    let pushType = PushTypes(rawValue: pushTypeStr) else {

        return

    }

    switch pushType {
  ```

case .report, .masteryBatch:

```
        if let payload = userInfo["payload"] as? String {
         
            if let dataFromPayload = PushNotificationModel(JSONString: payload) {
                
                PushnotificationNavigation.shared.chapterDetailNavigation(model: dataFromPayload)
                
            }
            
        }
```

Then I have called this NotificationHandler in appdelegate.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {
                    
        NotificationHandler.shared.handleNotification(userInfo)
        
    }
    
}
```

Can someone please provide guidance on how to handle push notification navigation to different views in the terminated/kill state of an iOS app, especially when using a tab bar controller?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please provide some code snipped to understand how you are dealing with navigation/redirection when app receives push.

Comment: @ShabnamSiddiqui Hello. I have edited above. Thankyou

Comment: please remove/comment `if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {` this block and just call `NotificationHandler.shared.handleNotification(userInfo)`. it will work.

Comment: It works only when the app is not in terminate state. I want to handle notification in terminated(when the app is not open) state.